# How to split a file based on context?

Tags: text-processing, osx, csplit

I have some files that contain the results of the `lldpneighbors` command from all our servers.  I would like to split these files into individual files for each server in order to make it easier to import this data into our inventory system.

**Sample Input**

```
=== Output from 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (SERVERNAME1):
Interface 'ixgbe0' has 1 LLDP Neighbors: 
Neighbor 1:
    Chassis ID:         MAC Address - 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Port ID:        Interface Name - TenGigabitEthernet 0/6
    Time To Live:       120 seconds
    System Name:        name-of-switch-01
    End Of LLDPDU:  
Interface 'igb0' has 1 LLDP Neighbors: 
Neighbor 1:
    Chassis ID:         MAC Address - 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Port ID:        Interface Name - TenGigabitEthernet 0/23
    Time To Live:       120 seconds
    System Name:        name-of-switch-02
    End Of LLDPDU:  
=== Output from 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (SERVERNAME2):
Interface 'ixgbe0' has 1 LLDP Neighbors: 
Neighbor 1:
    Chassis ID:         MAC Address - 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Port ID:        Interface Name - TenGigabitEthernet 0/2
    Time To Live:       120 seconds
    System Name:        name-of-switch-01
    End Of LLDPDU:  
Interface 'igb0' has 1 LLDP Neighbors: 
Neighbor 1:
    Chassis ID:         MAC Address - 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Port ID:        Interface Name - TenGigabitEthernet 0/19
    Time To Live:       120 seconds
    System Name:        name-of-switch-02
    End Of LLDPDU:
```

This is roughly what all the results look like with some variation(They are not all the same length, some are several lines longer because of more interfaces).  The delimiting string I would like to match on is:

```
=== Output from [UUID] ([HOSTNAME]):
```

Ideally I would like each file to be named the hostname(this would just be convenience and is not necessary), so above results would be split into files like:

**SERVERNAME1**

```
=== Output from 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (SERVERNAME1):
Interface 'ixgbe0' has 1 LLDP Neighbors: 
Neighbor 1:
    Chassis ID:         MAC Address - 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Port ID:        Interface Name - TenGigabitEthernet 0/6
    Time To Live:       120 seconds
    System Name:        name-of-switch-01
    End Of LLDPDU:  
Interface 'igb0' has 1 LLDP Neighbors: 
Neighbor 1:
    Chassis ID:         MAC Address - 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Port ID:        Interface Name - TenGigabitEthernet 0/23
    Time To Live:       120 seconds
    System Name:        name-of-switch-02
    End Of LLDPDU:
```

**SERVERNAME2**

```
=== Output from 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 (SERVERNAME2):
Interface 'ixgbe0' has 1 LLDP Neighbors: 
Neighbor 1:
    Chassis ID:         MAC Address - 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Port ID:        Interface Name - TenGigabitEthernet 0/2
    Time To Live:       120 seconds
    System Name:        name-of-switch-01
    End Of LLDPDU:  
Interface 'igb0' has 1 LLDP Neighbors: 
Neighbor 1:
    Chassis ID:         MAC Address - 00 01 02 03 04 05 
    Port ID:        Interface Name - TenGigabitEthernet 0/19
    Time To Live:       120 seconds
    System Name:        name-of-switch-02
    End Of LLDPDU:
```

I'm trying to use `csplit` to accomplish this but I'm not able to match the regex for some reason.   The commands I've tried:

```
$ csplit jbutryn_us-west-a_neighbors %===.*:% '{20}'
csplit: ===.*:: no match

$ csplit jbutryn_us-west-a_neighbors /===.*:/ '{20}'
552
552
552
csplit: ===.*:: no match

$ csplit jbutryn_us-west-a_neighbors '/===.*:/' '{20}'
552
552
552
csplit: ===.*:: no match

$ csplit -ks -f test jbutryn_us-west-a_neighbors '/===.*:/' '{20}'
csplit: ===.*:: no match
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk '/^===/{ fn=substr($NF,2,length($NF)-3) }{ print > fn }' file
```

Each file will be named according to *hostname* (`SERVERNAME<number>`)

- `/^===/` - on encountering line starting with `===`
- `fn=substr($NF,2,length($NF)-3)` - constructing filename `fn`, `substr($NF,2,length($NF)-3)` - will extract hostname ignoring parentheses around it (`$NF` - last field)
- `print > fn` - print underlying line into file

Comment: TY Sir.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't over-specify the regular expression:

```
$ csplit logfile '/^===/'
```

This creates `xx00` for the first section and `xx01` for the second.

Alternatively, if you have other lines starting with `===` that you *don't* want to split on:

```
$ csplit logfile '/^=== Output from/'
```

To replace `xx` with another fixed string, use `-p` (the string can't be taken from the input data unfortunately).

Comment: So this is only splitting the first occurrence of "=== Output from...".  I believe it's not liking my repetition count.

Comment: @Jesse_b I didn't need a repetition count for the data that you posted.

Comment: Yea but that is just a short sample as my input files are thousands of lines long I didn't want to make my question too long.